# Member Variable vs. Function Argument

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, struct

I´ve tried to figure out if it is faster to give a function an argument or simply use member variables. I have the following code.

```
class Variable
{
    private:

    public:
        Variable() {}
        ~Variable() {}

        struct
        {
            static const int test = 3;
        }testVar;
};

class VariableTransmit
{
    private:
        Variable var;

    public:
        VariableTransmit() {}
        ~VariableTransmit() {}

        void testFunc1(int test)
        {
            int foo = 2;
            foo = test;
        }

        void testFunc2()
        {
            int foo = 2;    
            foo = var.testVar.test;
        }

};

struct
{
    static const int test = 3;
}extVar;

int main(void)
{
    VariableTransmit transmit;

    clock_t prgstart, prgend;
    prgstart = clock();

    for(int i = 0; i <= 10000000; i++)
    {
        transmit.testFunc1(extVar.test);
    }

    prgend = clock();
    printf("delivered: %.5f seconds\n\n", (float)(prgend - prgstart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    prgstart = clock();

    for(int i = 0; i <= 10000000; i++)
    {
        transmit.testFunc2();
    }

    prgend = clock();
    printf("member: %.5f seconds\n\n", (float)(prgend - prgstart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

I tested this code and to my surprise testFunc1 and testFunc2 have identical processing speed. I had thought that testFunc1 would be the faster one since it gets the value as argument out of the struct and just has to set it, while testFunc2 has to access the var object and then get the value out of the struct inside the object. Is this compiler specific optimizing (I'm using VS2010 btw.) or did I just overlook something?

edit: Removed second question for being to opinion based.

Comment: Did you have optimizations turned on?  What were your results?

Comment: I would not be surprised If the compiler completely eliminates both loops. I'd like to see the timings that you got, or the generated assembler code.

Comment: I don`t have any specific optimisation flag used. I don't know if the vs2010 sets a default optimisation. If not then no optimisation. Both where at 0.023 sec.

Comment: Did you run in debug mode or release?  With that timing I would say both loops were optimized away as they are no ops.

Comment: Also your second question at the end is a different question then what is being asked here and that should be separate question.  I will caution you that the way it is it would be considered an opinion based question and put on hold.

Comment: It is a release. Thanks for the tip Nathan. I will look after an answer for the second question later myself.

Answer (score 0):

Your example will be highly optimized by the visual-c++ compiler. `testFunc1` might even be slower, depending on the register used to pass `test`, while `testFunc2` copies from *always the same* virtual adress.

Why is that?
Your `Variable var` is created on the stack. It will be created upon object creation, and thus the compiler can predict its virtual address. (You could create the `Variable` object on the heap and thus have a slightly longer execution time.)

[About the public/private-things: usually, you can do as you please. I - personally - believe, that in multithreaded environments, making internal structures of classes public poses a higher risk of accidental race conditions.]